# how to load a .repx file report to print

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, devexpress

I'm new to DevExpress and I created a `.repx` report using the `RibbonReportDesigner`. It's working fine in print preview reading from SQLite and loading the perfect design.
I saved the `.repx` file in project directory and changed its copy to output directory property to 'copy always'.

I have a button that should load this report, but I don't know what to do next and I couldn't find an answer online.

As shown in the attached picture I have a simple structure, Form1 takes several inputs from the user and generate a barcode, the barcode is well designed through `RibbonReportDesigner` but still I don't know the next step.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option that might better suit your needs would be to save the report to your project as a report class. Add a new DevExpress report object to your project and load your existing design from the `.repx` file.

When you want to print the document from your code, instead of instantiating a new `XtraReport` object and loading the layout from the `.repx` file, instantiate the `CustomReport.cs` class instead. Because your custom class is inherited from the `XtraReport` class, it will function the same and you can fill in your parameters like normal.